# Expand root "/" partition Centos 7 and VMWare

Tags: centos, centos7

I need to expand my root partition in a CentOS 7 server running in VMWare. I have already extended the storage in VMWare but now I'm a bit lost as I don't know what I need to do. `fdisk -l` of `/dev/sda` is:

```
 #         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048       411647    200M  EFI System      EFI System Partition
 2       411648      2508799      1G  Microsoft basic
 3      2508800     36063231     16G  Microsoft basic
```

The output of cat `/etc/fstab` is the following:

```
UUID=c6506014-31fd-404d-a7b0-4aa1af0e8d93       /       xfs     defaults,uquota0                                                                                                                                                                             0
UUID=8f488828-1345-4b37-b3c2-bcf3d6f7b0e0 /boot                   xfs     defaul                                                                                                                                                                             ts        0 0
UUID=BB9C-0CAE          /boot/efi               vfat    umask=0077,shortname=win                                                                                                                                                                             nt 0 0
UUID=de69324e-8403-41ca-8251-498dafc8ef2e       /home   xfs     defaults,uquota0                                                                                                                                                                             0
UUID=2ca01ff4-bdeb-4874-8271-05c0d5c7c66c swap                    swap    defaul                                                                                                                                                                             ts        0 0
/usr/tmpDSK             /tmp                    ext3    defaults,noauto        0                                                                                                                                                                              0
```

While the output of `parted -l` is the following:

```
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 59.8GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  211MB   210MB   fat16        EFI System Partition  boot
 2      211MB   1285MB  1074MB  xfs
 3      1285MB  18.5GB  17.2GB  xfs
```

My end goal is to expand `/dev/sda3` so that it takes until the end of the disk. I have read the documentation of `growpart`but not being a Linux expert I don't know if that is the correct way. I don't have LVM in my system.

Comment: `Microsoft basic` partition type? How have you done this? :)

Comment: @Krackout Linux mostly ignores the partition type in the GPT or MBR.

Comment: @Michael, still interesting how this type slipped when installing.
@Kabal, can you give the output of `parted -l`?

Comment: @Krackout, I have edited my question and included output of parted -l.

Comment: Ok, you don't have LVM. Mikael H's answer is correct; I'll suggest to use the same type, `Microsoft basic` for the new extended partition. it's a bit dangerous process, I suggest you take a full VM backup and proceed afterwards.

Comment: @Krackout, thank you very much. I will proceed with a full VM backup and with Mikael H's steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, make sure you have proper backups. You will effectively be destroying and recreating your data partition, so there's a small but non-zero chance of data loss.

**If you don't have LVM**, the process doesn't have many steps:

- Note the starting sector for sda3
- Enter fdisk and remove sda3
- Create a new primary partition from sda3's old starting sector to the end of the disk
- Write the partition changes to disk

Now you need to tell the OS about the new partition size, either by running `partx -u /dev/sda3` or by rebooting again.

After this, resize the partition with the appropriate tool (most likely `xfs_growfs`).

**If you do have LVM**, you need to insert the following steps after running `partx` or rebooting but before extending your actual file system:

- run `pvresize /dev/sda3` to make LVM see your entire partition size.
- run `lvextend -l 100%VG <your disks map ID>` to extend the logical volume.
- finally extend the file system as described above.

Comment: thank you for your answer. How can I create a new primary partition to the end of the disk? Is there a specific `fdisk` command?

Comment: After you delete the partition with the `d` command, create a new one with the `n` command. It will ask you the relevant questions, and the defaults tend to be sane. Don't forget to save your changes by `w`riting them rather than just `q`uitting fdisk.